# Definition of clique cover and clique edge cover

Tags: graph-theory

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover)

> The clique cover problem (also sometimes called partition into
>   cliques) is the problem of determining whether the vertices of a graph
>   can be **partitioned** into k cliques.

It seems to me that a clique cover is defined as a set of cliques that **partition** the vertices of the graph.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_edge_cover):

> An alternative definition of the intersection number of a graph G is
>   that it is the smallest number of cliques in G (complete subgraphs of
>   G) that together **cover** all of the edges of G. A set of cliques
>   with this property is known as a clique edge cover or edge clique
>   cover,

It seems to me that a clique edge cover is defined as a set of cliques that **cover** the vertices of the graph.

The two don't seem consistent to me. I searched in Douglas West's Introduction to Graph theory, Both clique cover and clique edge cover are defined in terms of cover instead of partition. So I wonder if the definition for clique cover in Wikipedia is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A **vertex clique cover** is a set of cliques that cover all the *vertices* of a graph.  If they overlapped, say two cliques shared the vertex $v$, we could simply delete $v$ from one of the two cliques and we'd end up with a vertex clique cover that is the same size or smaller (smaller if the clique was just $v$).  So, in this case, we go ahead and define the cliques to be disjoint.  The **vertex clique cover number** is the smallest number of such cliques needed to cover all the vertices.  This number would be the same whether we specified disjoint cliques or not, because if a minimum vertex clique cover contained cliques that overlapped, we could delete out vertices from one or the other until they no longer overlapped.  So, it is equivalent to partitioning the vertices into cliques.

An **edge clique cover** is a set of cliques that cover all the *edges*.  We can not guarantee that these will be disjoint, so talking about a partition makes no sense in this case.  Take a star, for example, $K_{1, 3}$.  To cover all 3 edges, we will need each edge to be a clique and all 3 cliques will contain the central vertex of the star.  Again, we can define the **edge clique cover number** as the smallest number of such cliques needed to cover all edges.

Thus, both could be considered in terms of covers, but only the vertex clique cover could be considered in terms of partitions.

It is clear from these definitions that vertex clique cover number is less than or equal to edge clique cover number.  Also, the vertex clique cover number of a graph is simply equal to the chromatic number of the complement of that graph.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67264/8671) for the basic idea of a proof.

Comment: Thanks! (1) "vertex clique cover number is less than or equal to edge clique cover number". Is it because from each edge clique cover, we can construct a vertex clique cover with the same size? (2) " the vertex clique cover number of a graph is simply equal to the chromatic number of the complement of that graph." Is it also true that the edge clique cover number of a graph is simply equal to the edge chromatic number of the complement of that graph?

Comment: @tim (1) It's because any edge clique cover must automatically cover all the vertices (okay, assuming the graph has no isolated vertices, I should have mentioned that) (2) No, good question, but I just looked up edge chromatic number and it's always either $\Delta$ or $\Delta + 1$ for every graph, where $\Delta$ is the largest degree.  But, edge clique cover number does not require this at all.  For example, any complete graph, $K_n$, has edge clique cover number 1, whereas it has edge chromatic number $n$.

Comment: In case of K_n,the smallest clique cover consists of  K_n only. So in that case w(K_n)=1 but we know it is 1+[log_2(n)].Can you tell me where I am goig wrong?